# Simple KTable Construction

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

**Conceptually**

Say I have a topic called "addresses" where the key is a person's name (String) and the value is a person's address (String). An update to the person's address would be a message consisting of their name as the key and a new address as the value. So, if I only want the most recent value for any one key, I suppose I would make a ktable. When I do that, what's actually going on here? Is Kafka creating a new topic which is actually the ktable and truncating old values? Or do I have to create a new topic for the current addresses? Or is it something else entirely?

**Practically**

All the examples and tutorials I'm finding are using deprecated methods, so I'm hoping for something newer. My current solution has been to read the topic like this:

```
final Properties config = new Properties();
//leaving out all the config.put() for readability

final Consumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(config);

consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList("addresses"));

try {
    while (true) {
        ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(200);
        for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
            //do stuff
        }
    }
} finally {
    consumer.close();
}
```

This worked for a while, but now I would like a stateful solution. Is there a simple way to just stick the information into a ktable as it comes in? I don't want to filter it or anything, I just want any entry to update the state. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The `KTable` does not create a new topic. Instead, it treats messages on the source topic like an *upsert* in a database - if it's the first time the key is seen, it's like inserting a new record. If it's not the first time, it's treated like an update to an existing record. The `KTable` can be used as inputs to other parts of Kafka Streams, and you could save that state in a local store as well and query that K/V store in other parts of your application.

Comment: Okay, so forgive my dumbing it down, but what you're saying is that a ktable is not necessarily stored anywhere (i.e. remotely), but is just creating a compilation of the data as pulled in from a stream and can then be stored locally if necessary?

Comment: Exactly. It's a particular view of a stream (could be from a topic, could be from multiple topics smashed together with stream operators).

Comment: A KTable by default uses a local embedded RocksDB to store the latest record per key. The input topic should be configured as compacted topic so no data is lost. (RocksDB is conceptually an ephemeral cache while the topic is the source of truth.) In case of failure, the input topic is used to re-create the KTable store before processing continues. This might help to some extend: https://www.slideshare.net/MatthiasJSax/ksqlstreaming-sql-for-apache-kafka (note that KSQL uses Kafka Streams as it's runtime)